# Nodejs - Extract a dynamic numerical value from an array of strings?

Tags: regex, node.js, parsing

I have command output that has been stored in an array of strings, and this numerical value could or could not exist in a string, and if it does exit it can be any integer value. I've tried various methods with regex and parseInt, and I am not getting the desired effect, I believe because of the way the string is encoded. How have others gone about this in the past?

EDIT:

The issue is the string is coming back, encoded as UT8. So the initial string I get is this: `disk: 40` Which I can reduce down to: 40 After that however, using a isNaN(decode_utf8(str)) Still produces a true for isNaN. I am not sure exactly how to overcome this

Comment: I guess others searched for "number regex javascript" at google.com, checked regular-expressions.info and studied regexone.com materials.

Comment: Can you give an example of the array data ?

Comment: The issue is the string is coming back, encoded as UT8. So the initial string I get is this:

`      disk: 40`

Which I can reduce down to:

`40`

After that however, using a `isNaN(decode_utf8(str))`

Still produces a true for isNaN.

I am not sure exactly how to overcome this.

Comment: decode_utf8 is a php function. You have tagged the question as node.js. Also, utf8 is javascript default. Why would you even try to decode it?

Comment: Because even without, it's still not recognising the number properly and returning true for isNaN.

Answer (score 0):

Try testing if a string is a number like this:

```
var toTest = "232";

if (!isNaN(+toTest)) {
    var aNumber = +toTest
    console.log('That is a number: ', aNumber)
```

if it must be a integer you could check like this:

```
    // check if integer ...
    var isInt = typeof aNumber === "number" && aNumber % 1 === 0;
}
```

If you are using latest JavaScript ES6 then isNumber is built in:

```
Number.isInteger(123)  // true
```

Comment: The issue is the string is coming back, encoded as UT8. So the initial string I get is this:

`      disk: 40`

Which I can reduce down to:

`40`

After that however, using a `isNaN(decode_utf8(str))`

Still produces a true for isNaN.

I am not sure exactly how to overcome this.

Comment: @VBM : That info should go in the question. It's pretty important ;) Also, where are you getting the data from? How can the format be reproduced? You must not be decoding it correctly if you cannot convert to a number.